Why are files inside a .tar object/file not being found when using Python?
I am working with python3 and using boto3.resource (s3_target = boto3.resource) and from this, I have access my bucket via s3_target.Bucket('dataset').
Ultimately, I wish to iterate through the bucket's .tar files and extract information about the .tiff files contained within the .tar files.
My problem however arises with accessing the .tiff files.
# Function to extract TIFF files from a tar archive
def extract_tiff_from_tar(bucket, tar_key):
    obj = bucket.Object(tar_key)
    response = obj.get()
    
    # Extract .tar file from S3 object
    tar_buffer = io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read())

    # Extract TIFF files from the .tar archive
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_buffer, mode='r') as tar:

        # Determine the size of the .tar file
        tar_size_bytes = sum(member.size for member in tar.getmembers())
        tar_size_gb = tar_size_bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        print(f"Size of the tar file: {tar_size_gb:.2f} GB")

        for member in tar.getmembers():
            # Filter the TIFF files
            if member.name.endswith('.tiff') and member.isfile():
                print("Current file type in tar: " + str(member.name))
                # Check if the file exists
                if os.path.exists(member.name):
                    print('This file exists: ' + str(member.name))

                # Use the try/except block to attempt to validate the existance of the TIFF
                try:
                    with open(member.name, 'rb') as tiff_file:
                        tiff = tf.imread(tiff_file)
                        print('This is the shape of the tiff: ' + str(tiff.shape))

                except FileNotFoundError as e:
                    continue


The code above provides the following output:
Size of the tar file: 1.59 GB
Current file type in tar: POW-xx0
This file exists: POW-xx0
This is the shape of the tiff: (2048, 3072, 15)
Current file type in tar: POW-xx1
Current file type in tar: POW-xx2

My question becomes, why is the line of code
if os.path.exists(member.name):
                    print('This file exists: ' + str(member.name))

Not executing, although the member.name is one of the files in the .tar file, as we can tell from the fact that it is being iterated over in each execution of the code piece
for member in tar.getmembers():

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I find it strange that there is no error for the very first member of the .tar object, however the following members, despite showing their name (is this also called their key?) are not evaluating to true when passed to the os.path.exists() method.

os.path.exists doesn't apply to files inside an archive. For the POW-xx0 that exists, it is probably in your current dir because you've extracted it manually before. Besides, If iteration yields the name, why checking for it?

Hi, thanks for the comment.
The file exists for the first item in the tar.getmembers():
After this however, the files apparently do not exist. I simply used the os.path.exist() to determine if the items in the tar.getmembers() did exist.
It seems however, that within this tar file, the 'key' associated with the members-excluding-the-first-one is invalid for accessing those files.
Re: pre-existing manual extraction - The code does not extract  the first item of the iteration until the code begins to iterate.

What are you checking, though? os.path.exists checks if the file exists in your file system, not the .tar file, so it's saying the first file in the tarchive already exists as a normal file in the directory you're looking in, and the other files don't. It's not that the code unpacks anything, but you having (partially) unpacked the first file at some point.

Part of the problem is that I am working via Python on an AWS using boto3. Inside the bucket, if I have understood it correctly, the file system is 'flat' - meaning no folders/subfolders. When I go through each member (object, aka file) of the .tarchive, I want to know it's key (aka file path) because for me to access the object, I need its key - as far as I understood.

I don't see how the response above addresses the problem: When you use os.path.exists, it's not checking what exists in S3, it's checking what exists on your computer.

Sorry, I am not very experienced with this kind of thing yet.
It is interesting then, that when I pass the method an argument it evaluates to true  for the first member in the .tar file. But not for the others. This is despite the fact that I am not working on my computer, I am working with files that are on the AWS and interacting with them via boto3. If the function evaluated to true for all of the filenames it was passed, then I would accept that. But what I don't understand is how it evaluated as true for the very first file.
I realize now that os.path.exists is meant for local pc, ty!

I found the answer to my problem, although I still am not sure what was going on in the initial problem.
If I use the tar.extract() method and pass the member of the .tarchive, it allows me to assign the returned value to a variable. From here, I can read it, change it to binary, and then use tifffile (here, tf) to read the image and access it.
Thanks for those who commented and I hope this helps somebody in the future. Do I need to close this post somehow now? Sorry, I'm new.
with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_buffer, mode='r') as tar:

    # Determine the size of the .tar file
    tar_size_bytes = sum(member.size for member in tar.getmembers())
    tar_size_gb = tar_size_bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
    print(f"Size of the tar file: {tar_size_gb:.2f} GB")

    for member in tar.getmembers():
        # Filter the TIFF files
        if member.name.endswith('.tiff') and member.isfile():

            a = tar.extractfile(member)
            tiff_data = a.read()
            tiff_io = io.BytesIO(tiff_data)
            tiff = tf.imread(tiff_io)
            print(tiff.shape)


extract() makes a copy of the file on your computer. Is this what you really want to do? (It does make the os.path.exists call return true, because that call is looking for a copy of the file on your computer, but it's not clear why you're making that call in the first place)

Well, I am no longer using the os.path.exists() function. Since I just want to be able to access the file contained within the .tar in the bucket on the AWS, I am using extract. I did not realize it created a copy of the file on my computer, I thought that it would only create the file temporarily for that iteration, allowing me to extract, for example, the pixel values of the .tiff file. If I am writing a script and it interacts with an s3 object (bucket) and I wanted to see the pixel values of a .tiff, is this only possible by downloading the .tiff file?

"The tar.extractfile() function doesn't create a local copy of the .tiff file on your local machine. Instead, it extracts the contents of the .tiff file from the .tar archive directly from the stream obtained from S3, allowing you to access its contents without storing it locally.
So, the .tiff file remains in the cloud, and you're just working with its contents in memory without storing it locally. This means you're not creating any additional copies of the file on your local machine."
Does this hold true? Or is it the incorrect understanding?

extract() and extractfile() are two different calls. extract() creates a local file, extractfile() creates a file-like object in-memory. In the comment above, I was responding to the text saying "if I use tar.extract()", not the code using tar.extractfile(). Which is all to say, yes, you're correct that extractfile doesn't create content on-disk.
